# User defined rest endpoints in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to allow the user to define a rest API and deploy it without having to restart the server. Essentially, they should be able to define endpoint: `/customInfo` followed by listing out the expected inputs and outputs and some command it should run. The command processing is handled in the back. It is not something I am worried about.

From whatever research I have done, the only approach I found is to use a controller with a wildcard `\*` like this, but this seems like a slightly janky approach.  Any help would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is something I've never seen anyone try before but...maybe you can fiddle around with something like this:

Have a single endpoint that takes in a "command" as the path variable. It can take  "freeform" Json as input and return freeform Json as the output. My example below uses the common `Map` approach.

This way, that "command" path variable will be whatever the client defines and the input and output are totally up to the client and the backend process.

```
@PostMapping("{command}")
public Map<String, Object> runCommand(@PathVariable String command, @RequestBody Map<String, Object> input) {
     return yourProcessingService.process(command, input);
}
```